# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'TransformerMixin' in this context

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the dataset about Titanic. But when I perform the pipeline, it a `TypeError`. Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class DataFrameSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, attribute_names):
        self.attribute_names = attribute_names
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.attribute_names]

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
try:
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer # Scikit-Learn 0.20+
except ImportError:
    from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer as SimpleImputer

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("select_numeric", DataFrameSelector(["Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare"])),
    ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
    ])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-4cae5bb1ad60> in <module>()
      7 
      8 num_pipeline = Pipeline([
----> 9     (("select_numeric", DataFrameSelector(["Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare"])),
     10      ('label_binarizer', MyLabelBinarizer())
     11         ("imputer", SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),)

TypeError: DataFrameSelector() missing 1 required positional argument: 'TransformerMixin'
```

Comment: Are you sure this is your actual code? It looks like you have a `def DataFrameSelector` instead of `class DataFrameSelector` somewhere.

Comment: thanks a lot for spotting my unbelievable error.